# Why does C++ Builder code editor not auto complete/ give parameters for ShellExecute but does for ShellExecuteW?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

In C++ Builder 11 (RAD Studio) and editing code, if I start typing "Shell" it doesn't bring up any auto completion options, if I hit `Ctrl-Space` then it starts showing stuff, going to `ShellExecute` it doesn't exist, but `ShellExecuteW` does, shouldn't it automatically offer the plain version knowing to use the `W` when linking?

Also, if I close the helpful hint that shows the parameters for the command, how do I get it to open that again, `Ctrl-Space` doesn't see seem to help with that.  I have to go back, erase the `(` and then type `(` again.

One other thing, is there a help link so if a Win API command is highlighted, F1 brings up context help for it like in Visual Studio?

I presume it's the same for Delphi which uses the same editor.

TIA!!

Comment: [_There’s no need to include greetings and sign-offs such as “Hi everyone!” and “Thanks – hope to get an answer soon” in the question._](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (linked from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Also: in my opinion abbreviations downgrade (the intended) respect - if there's not enough time to write out "_thanks_" then it's not truly meant either.

Comment: Sounds like the LSP server is *still* malfunctioning. Code completion in C++Builder has been so severely broken for years now, this is embarrassing. Which compiler (classic or clang) and which platform (32bit or 64bit) is your project using?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It must be using clang because the c++ class explorer isn't available.  It's 32bit platform by default (would add a 64bit as well, but didn't do that yet).

Comment: You can also try ``Ctrl + Shift + Space`` inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same spot, the only solution I could find is closing the project (not the C++ builder program) then going to file and open the project again and code completion will work like normal. No idea why it is like that